# How to describe a signed multiplier using the Verilog 1995 standard

Tags: verilog, multiplication

Using the 2001 standard signed multiplication is easy.

```
wire signed [7:0] A,B;
wire signed [15:0] Y;
assign Y = A*B;
```

I wonder how could this be done using the Verilog 1995 standard that has no 'signed' keyword.
Is there someone that remembers?

I do not have any idea on how to implement this in 1995 standard

Comment: Is there a reason to use Verilog 1995 that can be provided?

Answer (score 0):

According the the Sutherland text "Verilog-2001: " A Guide to the New Features of the Verilog Hardware Description Language"

"Verilog-1995 only provides one signed data type, the integer variable.  The reg, time, and all net data types are unsigned.  An integer variable has a fixed width of 32 bits (the IEEE standard defines integers as 'at lest 32 bits', but in virtually all simulators, integers are exactly 32 bits).  With only one signed data type in Verilog-1995, most signed operations are limited to 32-bits wide."

Wire is a net data type.

A little farther down he goes on to say:
"The limitation is Verilog-1995 is that to model signed arithmetic, only 32-bit integers can be used."

Comment: I read this but cannot figure out what this means and looks like a very big limitation

Answer (score 0):

You would have to explicitly sign extend A and B.

```
assign Y = {{8{A[7]}},A}*{{8{B[7]}},B};
```

I would not trust any tool that does not implement at least Verilog-2001.

Comment: This does not seem to work.
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/8FWE

Comment: You did not copy this code correctly. You need to replicate the sign bit

Answer (score -2):

Following Mikef answer I tried this.
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/EC5U

```html
module mult1995(A,B,Y);  

  input  wire [7:0] A,B;
  output wire  [15:0] Y;                    

  integer Inta,Intb,IntY;
  
  always@(A,B)
    begin
      Inta={{24{A[7]}},A};
      Intb={{24{B[7]}},B};
      IntY = Inta * Intb;
    end

  assign  Y=IntY[15:0];
endmodule
```

In simulation it seems to work (did not run an extended simulation).
I synthesized this with Quartus and it does implement a signed multiplier.

It looks like this is was the way to go.
Still there where a lot of problems if you needed more than 32 bits.

Comment: there is no need to use integer. And Quaruts certainly supports Verilog-2001